# Correspondence of ideals $J \subset I$ and ideals in $R/I$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I really have to know a few things though....
with that surjection map from ideals in a ring to ideals in a quotient ring by an ideal 
i.e. ( $\mathbf{R} \; \mapsto \; \dfrac{ \mathbf{R}}{ \mathbf{I}}$ ) that is a surjective homomorphism, why cant I do the simplest example of restricting the map to ideals containing $\mathbf{I}$ so the homomorphism is then bijective?

Here is an example of the process: $\mathbb{I} \; = \; \mathbf{3Z} \; and \;  \mathbf{5Z} \; = \; \{\; 0 \; , \; 3 \, , \; 5  \; , \; 6 \; , \; 8 \; , \; 9 \; , \; 10 \; , \; …. \; \} \; \mapsto \; the \; unit \; ideal \; \in \; \dfrac{\mathbf{Z}}{\mathbf{3Z}}$.
$\mathbb{I}$ contains $\mathbf{3Z}$ and so does the unit ideal in $\mathbf{Z} \; which \; also \; maps \; to \; the \; unit \; ideal \; in \dfrac{\mathbf{Z}}{\mathbf{3Z}}$. Do I really just make every single ideal one to one and onto the unit ideal?? Because well initially it doesn't even seem like a bijection when two ideals map to the unit ideal. The tutorials could all just tell that restricted to each ideal containing $\mathbf{I}$, the map is bijective. ; !

Comment: It's a little hard to figure out what's going on in this question - if you're asking whether the map between ideals of $R$ containing $I$ and the ideals of $R/I$ is bijective, this is true and it's known as the correspondence theorem for rings. Either way, please improve your question by adding context and making it clearer what your issue is.

Comment: I believe the op wants to understand the correspondence by looking at the example $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $I = 3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks it turns out that I used an operation for two ideals....

Answer (score 1):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is a field and therefore only has two ideals: The zero ideal and the field itself. Not every ideal is sent to the entire field, as for example $3\mathbb{Z}$ is mapped to the zero ideal. If you restrict the map to the ideals containing $3\mathbb{Z}$, you will only have two ideals left in your domain as $3\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ is maximal, namely the ideal $3\mathbb{Z}$ itself and the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. As I said before the ideal will get send to the zero ideal and the integers will get sent to the entire quotient and thus it is a bijection as you wanted.

Comment: So I take it that the theorem isn't for ideals with two generators?

Comment: The theorem works for arbitary ideals. Every ideal $I \subset \mathbb{Z}$ can be generated by one element and therefore you will not see any ideal needing two generators in that example.